# Disabling input is delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Export button on my page that is creating a PDF (this part is working).
During the export process I would like to disable some input or show an overlay to block the user to modify the page.
I'm using the code below:

```
function RenderSelectedChartJsToPDF() {
  // Option 1
  $('.featureInput').attr("disabled", true);
  $("#fileName").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#pdfExport").attr("disabled", true);
  // Option 2
  $("#overlay").show();

  window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
  const pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4', true);    //portrait or landscape

  var currentTopPosition = topMargin; // Initialisation of the working position.

  RenderPDFHeader(pdf, currentTopPosition);
  RenderPDFGeneralData(pdf, currentTopPosition);
  RenderPDFFooter(pdf, footerHight, 1, pdf.internal.pageCount);

  pdf.save($("#fileName").val() + '.pdf');

  // Re-enable input here
}
```

The issue is that when I click the export button the PDF will be render and at the end (when the download starts) then the inputs will be disabled.
I would like the input to be disabled first then start to build the PDF.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could let the PDF generation do its thing in the background so the browser has a chance to update the UI. Maybe look into [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: I set my function like this: async function RenderSelectedChartJsToPDF() {
    await DisabledInput(true); window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF; ... } But it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: No I mean separating the HTML attributes change from the PDF generation. First you set the attributes like you have and then you `await` the PDF generation, giving the browser time to update the UI while it awaits.

Comment: Like this: 
    async function RenderSelectedChartJsToPDF() {
    $('.featureInput').attr("disabled", true);
    $("#fileName").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#pdfExport").attr("disabled", true);
    await RenderPDF();
    ...
}
It doesn't work neither :(

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking. Weird. Are your `.attr("disabled", true);` calls working without generating the PDF? Can you provide a more complete example (use the `<>` button)?

Comment: Calls work fine but delayed. My input will be disabled after the PDF is downloaded.  `function DisabledInput(val) {
    $('.featureInput').attr("disabled", val);
    $("#fileName").attr("disabled", val);
    $("#pdfExport").attr("disabled", val);
}

async function RenderSelectedChartJsToPDF() {
    DisabledInput(true);
    await RenderPDF();
    await DisabledInput(false);
}

function RenderPDF() {
  window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
  const pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4', true);    //portrait or landscape
  ...
  pdf.save($("#fileName").val() + '.pdf');
}`

Comment: Update your question, don't write huge code snippets in the comment. Others might be able to help you and certainly don't want to read every single comment.

Comment: What happens if you move changing the inputs to a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? If that doesn't work it seems the PDF library is completely blocking the browser. Maybe set the inputs and half a second later start generating the PDF?

Comment: Looking at Promise as you said I found a similar issue to mine fixed by  `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1000); `  This is working for me. Thanks @PeterKrebs for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @PeterKrebs the issue seems to be the PDF library blocking the browser. I used a setTimeout function to solve my issue as follow:

```
function RenderSelectedChartJsToPDF() {
  $('.featureInput').attr("disabled", true);
  $("#fileName").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#pdfExport").attr("disabled", true);

  setTimeout(() => { RenderPDF(); }, 1000);    
}

function RenderPDF() {
  window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
  const pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4', true);    //portrait or landscape

  var currentTopPosition = topMargin; // Initialisation of the working position.
  RenderPDFHeader(pdf, currentTopPosition);
  RenderPDFGeneralData(pdf, currentTopPosition);
  RenderPDFFooter(pdf, footerHight, 1, pdf.internal.pageCount);
  pdf.save($("#fileName").val() + '.pdf');

  // Re-enable input here
}
```